# Stability for mapping class groups, spaces of sections, and polynomial coefficient systems

Tags: mapping-class-groups, mapping-space

Let $X$ be a simply connected space. Cohen and Madsen  https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601750 proved that the functor sending a surface with boundary M to $H_i(Map(M,X))$ has polynomial degree $\leq i$. Here Map means the space of maps which agree with the base point on the boundary. Polynomial degree is defined in that paper and is originally due Ivanov I believe. Does this generalize to spaces of sections? That is, if $E_M \to M$ is some bundle (say functorially built out of the tangent bundle of M) with preferred choice of section, is the functor sending $M$ to $H_i(\Gamma(E_M))$ polynomial of degree $\leq i$? Here $\Gamma$ means space of sections which agree with the basepoint section on the boundary. I am aware that Randal-Williams https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.4278v4 proved that $\Gamma(E_M)//Diff(M)$ has homological stability. For simplicity, all I care about is surfaces with one boundary component.